# How to HBase batch gets on Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase

I want to make RDD using HBase batch method because the rows which I want to get are separated.

When I use scan from HBase, I use newAPIHadoopRDD method.
I searched how to use batch method by this method.
But, I could not find it.

I know HBase normal batch API. But this API can not make RDD directory.
I need to make RDD for driver memory.

Environment
Spark 1.6.0
Use Scala

If anyone know how to use batch method on Spark,
please tell me about it.

Thank you.